# Fetch saved dynamic dropdown values via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

In my from I have a dynamic drop-down of `Category` and `Subcategory` which is working perfectly also I have successfully saved it's values in table `registrations` but when retrieving those values from `registrations` table with Ajax search only `Category` value is fetching but not `Subcategory` value.

I have tried to access `Subcategory` value same way as `Category` value was retrieved by Ajax get method but it's not working.

Script

```
//Search
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#search').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
    var sid = $("#search").val();
      $.ajax({
                  url: '{{ URL::to('search-data/')}}'+"/"+ sid,
                  type: "Get",
                  dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(response){ 
                    $('#CategoryID').val(response.category_name); 
                    $('#SubcategoryID').val(response.subcategory_name);
                 }
                });
            }
    });
     });
```

```
//Dynamic Drop-down
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CategoryID').on('change', function () {
            var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
            var CategoryID= $(this).val();
            if (CategoryID!= '') {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseurl + '/dropdown' + CategoryID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#SubcategoryID').empty();
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('#SubcategoryID').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#SubcategoryID').empty();
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div> 
  <label for="Category">Category</label> 
  <select class="form-control" name="Category" id="CategoryID">
 @foreach ($Category as $key => $value)
  <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value}}</option>
 @endforeach
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="Subcategory">Subcategory</label>
  <select name="Subcategory" class="form-control" id="SubcategoryID">
  <option>Subcategory</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
//Dynamic Drop-down
 public function getSub(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
        $sub = DB::table("subcategories")->where("category_id", $id)->pluck("name");
            return Response::json($sub);
        }
    }
```

```
//Data Retrieve
public function dataSearch($sid)
    {
        $search = Reg::find($sid);
        return Response::json($search);
    }
```

Comment: I think we will be more interested in the controller function you want to give you data. chances are that you did not load the subcategories on the query

Comment: Updated my question with `Controller`, please check now.

Comment: It looks like you have a ```Category``` model and a ```SubCategory``` that belongsTo Category. So you can load the subcategories using eager-loading ie ```Category::with('subcategory')```. You controller code kinda tells a lot, you will have to give yourself a few minutes studying Eloquent and relationships. It will help you lots in the future

Comment: Those models have no issues, they are doing their job to populate data and I have also successfully saved those values to database in `Registration` table with `Reg` model but my question is how can I fetch those saved values (category_name and subcategory_name) using Ajax from `Registation` table?

Comment: @AbdulRehman have a look at it, please.

Comment: try adding ```->get()``` after ```pluck```

Comment: @Flash I doubt this will work because I'm trying to fetch saved value from registation table where my all form data is already saved and your solution will only work before save.

Comment: @Flash I'm sure there is something wrong in my ajax search part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution for it:

`$("#SubcategoryID :selected").text(response.subcategory_name);`

This will get text of currently selected drop-down from database.